# StreamBuilder Unexpected null value

Tags: flutter, firebase, null

The data is successfully updated to firebase but the data does not show on screen. When I run the code, a red screen shows up saying "unexpected null value". Here is the code.

```
child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("Users")
            .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
            .collection("Coins")
            .snapshots(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data!.docs.length > 0) {
            return ListView(
                children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
              return Container(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Text("Coin Name: ${document.id}"),
                    Text("Amount owned: ${document.data()['Amount']}"),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }).toList());
          }
          //  else {
          ConnectionState == ConnectionState.waiting;
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
          // }
        },
      ),
```

Here is the error message.

The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building StreamBuilder(dirty, state:
_StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot, AsyncSnapshot>#1c684):
Unexpected null value.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
StreamBuilder
StreamBuilder:file:///C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/flutter%20tutorial/authentication_page/lib/ui/home_page.dart:24:18

Comment: looks like `snapshot.data` is null the first time the builder is called, for more read the official docs of `StreamBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (snapshot.hasData) {
   if (snapshot.data!.docs.length > 0) {
            return ListView(
                ...
 }
```

try using it like this.